# How to switch iOS Private app to Public App

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, developer-tools

I have recently made an iOS iPhone app and after review apple team had asked for it to be private. This app was targeted as a project management/tracker app which, and the login was to be delivered by the organization of the employee and so strictly speaking the app had a closed off environment. I adhered to apple's request to make it a private app but only later did I come to know that private apps aren't available in play store and it required apple business manager account(does it require a fee?) which I don't have. I just have a apple developer account. So I now want to change the app back from private to public and the button which lets you switch in the AppStore connect seems to be greyed out now and I'm not able to do that now.

**TL;DR**: I want to switch my iOS app from private to public and this is after an existing release. And the switching option in appstore connect seems to be greyed out.

Comment: Apple Business Manager is free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an app has been released as a private app, it [cannot be changed back to a public app.](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev275598f16)

> **I currently have an app that is available privately in Apple Business Manager and I’d like to make it available publicly on the App Store, can I change my app’s distribution method?**
>
> No. To change your app’s distribution method from public to private, or vice versa, please create a new app and submit it for review.

Even if you could change it, it seems likely that Apple would reject it for the same reason they rejected it last time.